# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: isBlack is not defined

Tags: javascript, async-await

I het the error from the title in browser console with this code:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  betterBlitzColor();

  let isBlack = true;
  function animate() {
    $(".playerInfoCoatTwo").animate({
      backgroundColor: isBlack ? "transparent" : 'black'
    }, 20);
    isBlack = !isBlack;
  }

  // Delay function,
  // allows for much flatter code when you can `await` a `Promise` compared to `setTimeout`:
  const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
  async function animateAndWait(msArr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < msArr.length; i++) {
      // debugger;
      animate();
      await delay(msArr[i]);
    }
  }

  async function betterBlitzColor() {
    console.log(isBlack);
    await animateAndWait([20, 300, 50, 150, 50, 50]);
    if (myRandomNumberBetween(1, 100) <= 0) {
    console.log(isBlack);

      return delay(myRandomNumberBetween(9000, 18000))
        .then(betterBlitzColor);
    }
    await animateAndWait([650, 300]);
    if (myRandomNumberBetween(1, 100) <= 0) {
    console.log(isBlack);

      return delay(myRandomNumberBetween(9000, 18000))
        .then(betterBlitzColor);
    }
    await animateAndWait([400, 100, 100, 150]);
    console.log(isBlack);

    delay(myRandomNumberBetween(9000, 18000))
      .then(betterBlitzColor);
  }


  // console.log(myRandomNumberBetween(1, 5))
  function myRandomNumberBetween(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }
  }); // end of jQuery(document).ready(function()
```

IF I remove the lines:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
}); // end of jQuery(document).ready(function()
```

again the same error. But if I move the line:

```
}); // end of jQuery(document).ready(function()
```

I have not errors. I have no Idea what is going on... Someone Help.

In HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="js/typed.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/1.1.1/typed.min.js"></script>  
<script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
```

I have seen a lot of guys have the same problem here yet can't manage to find any solution for me.

I cnaged let to var on isBlack and then got error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: delay is not defined
```

Then changed to this:

```
var delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
```

And I got error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: delay is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should invoke `betterBlitzColor` *after* everything it depends on has been defined. Put it *after* the variable declarations, not before. Function declarations are hoisted, but any other assignments are not. Also note that if you're using a modern version of jQuery, you can use `$(function() {` (or `$(() => {` rather than `jQuery(document).ready(function(){`, to make the script a bit easier to read. For example:

```
$(() => {
  let isBlack = true;
  const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
  betterBlitzColor();
  // ...
```

You could also change `delay` to a function declaration, if you really wanted to, which will result in it being hoisted and allow you to invoke `betterBlitzColor` on a higher line in the code, but it makes the code a bit uglier IMO:

```
$(() => {
  let isBlack = true;
  betterBlitzColor();
  function delay(ms) {
    return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
  }
  // ...
```

Comment: Ok thanks again! Obviously I have a lot more to learn. Thanks for everyones time guys.

Comment: Took you all of 2 seconds to answer after OP added the _real code_. You knew that edit was coming, didn't you ;-)